# Как передать и использовать php-переменную в шаблон Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, шаблонизаторы

Нужно передать переменную в шаблон, типа

```
$t_inc = new TPL('.tpl/'.$page['tpl'].'/tpl/'.$page['tpl_list']);
$t_inc->assign('pages', 3);
```

После чего использовать её

```
<div id='tmp'>{$pages}</div>
```

Но ничего не интерпритируется, выводится как есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: debug в смарти включи что показывает?

Comment: этот проект я лишь дорабатываю, поэтому сборкой занимался не я.
в проекте отсутствует файл debug.tpl (http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/chapter.debugging.console.tpl) ...

Comment: ладно попробуй скопировать page  из переменной в assign в  шаблон )

Comment: не понял как это сделать :)
я не могу assignу присваивать ничего,, это ж метод

Answer (score 1):

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->setCacheDir($this->cachePath);
$smarty->setCompileDir($this->compiledPath);
$smarty->setTemplateDir($this->templatePath);
$smarty->caching = false;
$smarty->compile_check = true;
$smarty->assign('pages', 3);
echo $smarty->fetch(dirname($this->templatePath)."/{$this->template}.tpl";);
```

Попробуйте на чистом Smarty. Вполне возможно что бага где-то в обертках